Remote tunnel error when trying to keep the tunnel active
I'm trying to start remote tunnel with:
code tunnel --no-sleep

However I get the following error:
[2024-06-30 09:13:27] warn Could not inhibit sleep: error requesting sleep inhibition, pminhibitor gave org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit was not provided by any .service files, screensaver gave: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver was not provided by any .service files

The tunnel itself is working, also with nohup. However with the --no-sleep flag I get this error.
MPI and Python are installed.
